# Time Varying 3D Vector Plot Improvements

Tags: plotting, graphics

From another question, I got curious and used Mathematica's built-in features to analyze the following.

$$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = 1.0(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \sin( ~t) - 1.0\sin(t+\pi/2) \\ \dot{y} = 1.1(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \sin(2t) - 1.1 \sin(2t+\pi/2) \\ \dot{z} = 1.2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \sin(3t) - 1.3 \sin(3t+\pi/2) \end{cases}$$

I used [*VectorPlot3D*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot3D.html) as

```
  Manipulate[
   VectorPlot3D[{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) Sin[t] - Sin[t - Pi/2], 
   1.1 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) Sin[2 t] - 1.1 Sin[2 t + Pi/2], 
   1.2 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) Sin[3 t] - 1.3 Sin[3 t + Pi/2]}, {x, -2 Pi, 
   2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]], {t, -10, 10}]
```

It works, but the vector plots are hard to view.

Is there any way to improve the results to allow more easily viewing them or to use [*StreamPlot*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html) or [*ParmatericPlot3D*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) or some other way that allows users to view more details from the plots?

Comment: Have you tried playing with `VectorScale` which is an option to `VectorPlot3D`?  You can also change the `ViewPoint`.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I played around with both and they only provide marginal improvements, but not for all $t$.

Comment: "the vector plots are hard to view": can you be more specific about what is hard to view, and what would be a better representation in your opinion? I tried your code and I could see the vector arrows and manipulate values just fine.

Comment: @MarcoB: Thanks. Look at the results for $t = -4$, for example. You cannot see the detail of the 3D vector plot. Use Manipulate[
 VectorPlot3D[{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) Sin[t] - Sin[t - Pi/2], 
     1.1 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) Sin[2 t] - 1.1 Sin[2 t + Pi/2], 
     1.2 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) Sin[3 t] - 1.3 Sin[3 t + Pi/2]}, {x, -2 Pi,
      2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
    VectorScale -> Automatic] PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}], {t, -10, 
  10}] . In the top portion of the plot, it is very hard to ascertain anything. Is there some way to add color to make the entire plot more easy to decode?